# Graphivz does not render edge label when it's connecting two nodes with shape=point

Tags: rendering, graphviz, dot

I have the following graph description:

```
graph G {
    {rank=same a b}
    a[shape=point]
    b[shape=point]
    a -- b [label=e];
}
```

However, it outputs a single edge without a label (running graphviz with `dot -Tpdf -o test.pdf test.dot`):

[image]

Rendering to PNG yields same result. If I render it to PDF and then look for an "e" in the document, the following are is highlighted:

[image]

So, the edge label is here but it's invisible somewhy.
Surprisingly, if I switch rank direction, everything works:

```
graph G {
    rankdir=LR;
    a[shape=point]
    b[shape=point]
    a -- b [label=e];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer really as I cannot provide any explanation but what I have observed is: As long as there is any other character / label rendered in the graph, 
the `e` will also be rendered.

Interestingly enough this even applies for labels that are explicitly set to invisible, so if you compile

```
graph G 
{
    { rank=same;  a;  b; }
    a [ shape = point ];
    b [ shape = point ];
    a -- b [ label = "e" ];
\\  add this
    c [ style = invis ];
}
```

you get what you want:

[image]

The graph area will increase, though.